# @parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parcel

I am using parcel with React in an application. When I am running

`npx index.html`

it is showing me below error:

Server running at http://localhost:1234
 Build failed.

@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'react' from
'/home/Code/React/node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js'

/home/Code/React/node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js:13:24
12 | export { AbortedDeferredError, Action as NavigationType, createPath, de

> | 13 | import * as React from 'react'; |
> | --- | --- |
> | 14 |  |
> | 15 | function _extends() { |

@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot find module 'react'

Not sure what is wrong here as this thing was working few months back and suddenly facing this error now.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're running `npx index.html`?

Comment: Yeah I am running this command